# How to get innerHTML of ReactDOM mounted element

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

HTML markup like this:

```
<div id="my-component">
    <div>Some content goes here</div>
</div>
```

Having this in `app.js` file:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById('my-component));
```

I want to get innetHTML of `#my-component` before that react component is mounted.

Using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` in `componentWillMount` is not working because the element is not still mounted so returns null and in `componentDidMount` innerHTML has been replaced.

Comment: If the element is not actually mounted, then you can supply the component it's html instead of requiring it. Don't you think?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I see this is not a real react issue. We are using react in a PHP website for just some components like Cart and Swipers. Because we don't want to fetch the component content using Ajax I want to let the PHP developers to add a simple markup in component.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to achieve this:

```
const el = document.getElementById('my-component');
ReactDOM.render(
  <App>{el.innerHTML}</App>,
  el
);
```

Then in my react component I can render the html like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.children}}></div>
  );
}
```